# soon-to-be ex-wife or soon-to-be-ex-wife

Tags: punctuation

Is it:

his 'soon-to-be ex-wife' or his 'soon-to-be-ex-wife'?

Do we need that hyphen after the word 'be'? If so, why? If not, why not?

And is it:

'his soon-to-be-ex' or 'his soon-to-be ex'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

'Soon-to-be ex-wife' is the optimal format. You have two distinct components: the compound adjective *soon-to-be* and the noun it describes, *ex-wife*. The hyphens tie together the individual elements in each of these.

'Soon-to-be-ex-wife' is unsuitable because it is confusing: the inclusion of a hyphen after *be* would improperly erase the distinction between the compound adjective and the noun it describes.

By the same token, the abbreviated form should be written 'soon-to-be ex', not 'soon-to-be-ex'.

Comment: +1 @Erik Kowal - excellent. Pithy post. This type of answer is very helpful to untutored ... me. I knew the answer but not the terms.

Comment: @LittleEva - Thanks for your positive remarks. By all means, feel free to underscore them by upvoting my answer. :)

Comment: Oh, but I do! What I lack in cash I make up for with praise. Why Erik, I'm *positively* profligate.

Comment: Very helpful -- thank you. I think the only time we'd use hyphens throughout is when the entire phrase functions as an adjective: "His soon-to-be-ex-wife, Martha, will be there." Do you agree? Thanks again.

Comment: @whippoorwill if you are going to hyphenate between two elements that were already hyphenated compounds, then you can use an en-dash to make the grouping clearer (*soon-to-be–ex-wife*). As with other compounds you can do so or not whether used as a modifier or not, but the advantages are greater when it is used as a modifier.

Comment: I think the en dash could possibly confuse the reader, no?

Comment: You could have *soon-to-be-ex wife*!